# C++ is it possible to bind multiple methods together?

Tags: function, c++11, stdbind

I would like to call a method after another method using std::function. Suppose i have something like this

```
class foo
{

   std::function<void(int)> fptr;

   void bar(int){
   }
   void rock(){
   }
public:

   foo() {
       fptr = bind(&foo::bar,this,std::place_holder::_1); //<------Statement  1
   }
}
```

Now because of statement 1 if i call `fptr(12)` the method bar is called.
My question is can i specify or manipulate statement 1 so that after bar is called it calles `rock`. I know i could simply have `bar` calle `rock` but thats not what i am looking for.  Can bind help me accomplish this ?

Comment: sorry that was a typo i wanted rock to be called

Comment: Where is the `std::string` to pass to `rock` supposed to come from?

Comment: make it simple - suppose there is no string. I am exploring my options

Comment: Why not use a lambda instead of binding?

Comment: Yes that would definitely be an option - could you put that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::bind` won't really help here, but a lambda will.

```
fptr = [this](int n) { bar(n); rock(); };
```